# Pyspark org.apache.spark.sql.avro.IncompatibleSchemaException

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, avro

I'm running pyspark and trying to read some avro files in. The avro files are stored in AWS S3. The script goes something like:

```
df = spark.read.format('avro').load('/path.avro')
df.checkpoint()
```

However, I'm getting this bug. Notably, it occurs only sometimes for the same input files:

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.avro.IncompatibleSchemaException:
> Cannot convert Avro to catalyst because schema at path dummy.lat is
> not compatible (avroType = "double", sqlType = FloatType).

I investigated further and dummy.lat is indeed stored as a double. It used to be stored as a float in our database.

Why is this causing an issue? Isn't spark able to infer schema?

Comment: Your Dev & Prod both have same version or diff version ?

Comment: I think it's same version of pyspark - good catch. Also, I incorrectly said it only happens in Prod - it sometimes happens in Dev too. It's random when it occurs; same input files sometimes will bug and sometimes won't.

Answer (score 0):

Double to Float is not listed as a supported conversion: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html

You could try changing your SQL Type to Double.